# IF with && (multiple condition) variant data-type error

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have query on IF cond. with && (and).

When I'm using single if condition like:

```
Column =
IF (
    'For PwerBi'[Cert type for TAT] = "Midterm Routine"
        && INT ( 24 * 'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays] ) > 8,
    ">8Hrs",
    "NA"
)
```

I am not getting an error and output comes.

But, when I add one IF condition like:

```
Column =
IF (
    'For PwerBi'[Cert type for TAT] = "Midterm Routine"
        && INT ( 24 * 'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays] ) < 8,
    INT ( 24 * [TAT excluding weekends_holidays] ),
    "NA"
)
```

it gives me an error:

> "Expressions that yield variant data-type cannot be used to define
>   calculated columns."

I don't understand the meaning of this error. Why does it appear?

Here is my original dax formula-

```
Column 2 = IF('For PwerBi'[Cert type for TAT]="MR" && INT(24*'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays])>8,">8Hrs",

IF('For PwerBi'[Cert type for TAT]="MR" && INT(24*'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays])<=8,FORMAT( INT ( 24 * [TAT excluding weekends_holidays] ), "0" ), 

IF('For PwerBi'[Cert type for TAT]="MRR" && 'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays]<TIMEVALUE("00:30:00"),"<30Min",

IF('For PwerBi'[Cert type for TAT]="MRR" && 'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays]>=TIMEVALUE("00:30:00") && 'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays]<TIMEVALUE("01:00:00"),"30 Min - 1 Hr",

IF('For PwerBi'[Cert type for TAT]="MRR" && 'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays]>=TIMEVALUE("01:00:00") && 'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays]<TIMEVALUE("01:30:00"),"1 Hr - 1.5 Hr",

IF('For PwerBi'[Cert type for TAT]="MRR" && 'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays]>=TIMEVALUE("01:30:00") && 'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays]<TIMEVALUE("02:00:00"),"1.5 Hr - 2 Hr",

IF('For PwerBi'[Cert type for TAT]="MRR" && 'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays]>=TIMEVALUE("02:00:00") && 'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays]<TIMEVALUE("02:30:00"),"2 Hr - 2.5 Hr",

IF('For PwerBi'[Cert type for TAT]="MRR" && 'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays]>=TIMEVALUE("02:30:00") && 'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays]<TIMEVALUE("03:00:00"),"2.5 Hr - 3 Hr",

IF('For PwerBi'[Cert type for TAT]="MRR" && 'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays]>=TIMEVALUE("03:00:00") && 'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays]<TIMEVALUE("03:30:00"),"3 Hr - 3.5 Hr",

IF('For PwerBi'[Cert type for TAT]="MRR" && 'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays]>=TIMEVALUE("03:30:00") && 'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays]<TIMEVALUE("04:00:00"),"3.5 Hr - 4 Hr",

IF('For PwerBi'[Cert type for TAT]="MRR" && 'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays]>=TIMEVALUE("04:00:00"),"> 4 Hr",

IF('For PwerBi'[Cert type for TAT]="Rnw" && INT(24*'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays])<8,"< 8 Hrs",

IF('For PwerBi'[Cert type for TAT]="Rnw" && INT(24*'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays])>=8 && INT(24*'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays])<16,"8 - 16 hrs",

IF('For PwerBi'[Cert type for TAT]="Rnw" && INT(24*'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays])>=16 && INT(24*'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays])<24,"16 - 24 hrs",

IF('For PwerBi'[Cert type for TAT]="Rnw" && INT(24*'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays])>=24 && INT(24*'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays])<36,"24 hrs - 36 hrs",

IF('For PwerBi'[Cert type for TAT]="Rnw" && INT(24*'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays])>=36 && INT(24*'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays]),"36 hrs - 48 hrs",

IF('For PwerBi'[Cert type for TAT]="Rnw" && INT(24*'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays])>=48,"> 48 hrs",

IF('For PwerBi'[Cert type for TAT]="NA","NA",INT(24*'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays])))))))))))))))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your measure cannot output both numbers and text. You have to pick one or the other. In the first measure, both results are text. In the second, your `True` result is a number and your `False` result is text.

To fix this, you can convert the number to text using the [`FORMAT` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/format-function-dax):

```
Column =
IF (
    'For PwerBi'[Cert type for TAT] = "Midterm Routine"
        && INT ( 24 * 'For PwerBi'[TAT excluding weekends_holidays] ) < 8,
    FORMAT( INT ( 24 * [TAT excluding weekends_holidays] ), "0" ),
    "NA"
)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks Alexis, for your reply and guidance. I wanted to share my original formula here.. I'm getting an error in the same.         
Error - "Expressions that yield variant data-type cannot be used to define calculated columns."

Comment: @PowerBiBeginer The answer is the same. You need to make all output text which means formatting your last line's output.